# A way to plot properties of vertices (eg height vs distance)?

Tags: modeling, mesh, path

I am just starting modeling terrain with Blender, and I tried to find some tool which could help me modeling things like rivers and roads. More precisely, I am looking for some way to plot the elevation of a selected set of vertices against their cumulated distance. I could then use that plot to if the gradient looks good or if (and at which point) I need to modify it. Does anyone know if there is something around which does that? Or something which could be used as a basis to build such a tool on?

EDIT: I imagine a plot which looks something like what you could for example find as height information when looking at bike tracks in google maps:

[image]

Comment: hello, could you show with a picture what " plot the elevation of a selected set of verticies against their cumulated distance" means?

Comment: Ah, yes, sure. I should have don that from the beginning. I added it to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took me a while but I now found a decent setup (it is by no means perfect but I will come to that later). It makes heavy use of Animation Nodes with a similar concept as the answer from @Chris.

The first step is to trace the desired path on the ground mesh. Snap to face should be activeted for this (or alternatively I have found a 2D path on the xy-plane tracing only the projection of teh desired path to also work well).
[image: path being traced by hand along teh desired path]

In the second step, a higher resolution path is generated using AN (node setup below, for me the first path is "gadangBed_maxR" and the output is written into "gadangBed_maxR_hr"). Make sure to have the Step size low enough to capture every relevant feature (you can also change this later and it will adopt everything on the fly).
[image: Animation Nodes setup for the high resolution path generation, choose the resolution (red oval) appropriately]
A shrink wrap modifier targeting the ground mesh is added to the high resolution path.
[image: Shrinkwrap settings for the high resolution path]

The last step is to generate a path tracing the height vs the distance. Below is the AN setup for this. Make sure you have "Use Modifiers" enabled on the input. The multiplication for the z-axis and the Bevel Depth can be chosen to whatever value makes the result easiest to look at.
[image: Animation nodes setup to generate the final height path]
[image: Animation Nodes subprograms used]

I like to put the resulting height path in a seperate scene collection and then make this scene collection invisible for the main window. I then open another 3D viewport, enable "Local Collections" and only make the scene collection with the height path visible (red circle in picture below). I made two path in different colors.
[image: height path in additional viewport]

The created height path shoud now automaticaly update whith the ground mesh, allowing tem to be used in real time for sculpting the ground.

The problems which I still see with this method (but have no idea how to improve):

- The original path does not move with when the ground mesh changes, this can make it more tedious to adjust the path later on.
- It is sometimes hard to see which part of the height path is where on the ground mesh, you can not simply for example select a point on the height mesh and it shows you where the equivalent point on the ground mesh is.

Answer (score 2):

Again - you can do this with animation nodes (it's just an amazing tool!)

preparation:

I added a plane, subdivided a lot and gave it a displace modifier.

Then i selected some vertices (will be my path), copied them and separated them by selection, so i got a "own" mesh, then converted that to a curve (the green line in the picture).
Then in animation nodes i can "ask" the curve (called spline in AN) for it's points and iterate over them.
I then just took the distance between the points as x-coordinate (added of course) and let the y-coordinate be 0 and let the z-coordinate as it is (yes, you can do an add and multiply with both so that you "see" more) and the result:

[image]

node tree:

[image]

i added a more "obvious" line of vertices (just a straight line in x direction, so you see it works) with colors:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, Animation Nodes really seems like a powerful tool for these kind of things (It took me until now to reall find enough time to propperly have a look at this). However, with that solution, the final curve does not change when the position of the original nodes changes. I tried to have it use a vertex group instead of the extra mesh but so far I didn't manage to do it. Maybe you know a way to achieve something like that that?

Answer (score 2):

If your incoming path is a single spline.. (you could always convert it in GN) Geometry Nodes will do this quite naturally.. here,  `Curve parameter * Curve Length` is mapped to the Y axis, X is set to a constant, and Z is corresponding  height of the original path. Of course, those axes can be swapped around, and scaled to your liking...

[image]

The original path curve has been resampled to the desired graph resolution, and converted to a *Poly* type, to avoid distortions from any Bezier handles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: so simple and so ingenious

Comment: @Chris Thank you! This stuff is still giving me brain-ache, though.. my mental picture of which attributes stick where, when everything is anonymous, is _very_ fuzzy. :(

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to describe something along the length of an arbitrary path, I would use a path-- a curve object.

[image]

We start by tracing out both our height and our path with vertices.  The origin for each needs to be at the start of the path.  Then we convert the path to a curve.  I set the curve, in properties/object data/shape, to stretch and to bounds clamp, and the twist mode to Z-up.  (I also converted it to a Bezier, with auto-handles, but it's up to you.)

Then the height gets some subdivision to create enough vertices, is colocated with the curve, and gets a curve modifier.  It requires rotation (here, in its local X) in order to agree with the path axes, since I drew the height with height pointing in global Y.

To help with the display, I've also created some thickness for the height, and exaggerated the height four-fold.

If we want to incorporate this into some other geometry, we can shrinkwrap/project Z that geometry onto this mesh, or we can render this object as a height map and paste it into an existing height map.  Either will require some further editing to clean up the transition.